# Cucumber - DocStringType - Jackson Data Bind UnrecognizedPropertyException - Even If Property Existed

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, jackson-databind

Below is my Feature File

```
Scenario Outline: CucumberTest
    Given Generate Data Set
    """json
      {
         "tcIdentifier":"TC1"
      }
      """
    Examples:
      |TESTCASEIDENTIFIER|
      |TC1                |
```

Step Defintion Would Look Like Below

```
 @Given("Generate Data Set")
        public void generateDataSet(DataSetMetaData dataSetMetaData) {
    
            System.out.println(dataSetMetaData);
        }



@DocStringType
    public DataSetMetaData createTestDataForSorting(String details) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(details, DataSetMetaData.class);
    }

Details of the DataSetMetaData

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DataSetMetaData {
    private String tcIdentifier;
}
```

**Expected : Data Binding from the Docstring to be Transformed to DataSetMetaData POJO**

ACtual : We Are Encountered with the Exception
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "tcIdentifier"  not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])

From Some of the Previous Responses on similar - Exception - community has suggested to Annotate the Field as @JsonProperty - What I am Failing to Understand - if the variable Names matches the JSON Data Key   - Ideally Binding Should work - For some Strange Reason - even if the attribute Exist - UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "tcIdentifier"

Following are the maven Co-ordinates related to the Cucumber and Jackson Dependencies

implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '7.3.4
implementation group: 'net.logstash.logback', name: 'logstash-logback-encoder', version: '7.2'

Do let me know if any Further Information is required

Comment: Can you try and reproduce this without Cucumber? It doesn't seem to add anything to the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you have Jackson annotations on the class itself? Or a combined Jackson/Lombok one?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje - You are spot on - its my lack of Attention - Made me Connect to Cucumber - it was nothing to do with Cucumber - even with normal Deserialization  via Jackson Library - from String to POJO was failing

Comment: @GaëlJ - I do not have any Jackson Annotations on the Class - But i had Lombok Annotations of @Builder/@Getter/@NoArgsConstructor/@AllArgsConstructor

Answer (score 0):

@M.P. Korstanje and @GaëlJ - Thank you very much for insights and giving directions towards analysis in the right Direction

Adding the Lombok Dependencies with the scope of annotationProcessor did the magic - Hope it Helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).